# Not able to access a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to access a site collection using browser, but i am not able to access it.

error:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Tue, 24 Mar 2015 05:08:38 GMT
Connection: close

i am also not able to create a new site collection.
error:
Something went wrong

I am using SharePoint 2013

Comment: Please check the ULS log entries and also event viewer entries for any error information

Comment: do you have top level permissions?

Comment: yes i do have top level permission

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and here is fix in our case.

- from central admin detach the content database( attached to prolematic web app).
- wait for couple of min or if you can reset IIS
- attach the content database to the web app using the powershell `Mount-SPContentDatabase "MyDatabase" -DatabaseServer "MyServer" -WebApplication http://sitename`

If it fails, do again but give some break between attaching and detaching.